# How to sample an item from a variable

Tags: select, random, subset, stata, sample

I have a large unbalanced panel dataset, which looks as follows:

```
clear

input year id income
2003 513 500
2003 517 500
2003 518 100
2003 525 900
2003 528 800
2003 531 0
2003 532 300
2003 534 600
2004 513 1000
2004 517 120
2004 523 300
2004 525 700
2004 528 800
2004 531 200
2004 532 600
2004 534 100
end
```

I want to randomly sample some people by `id`. `id` range has gaps in positive natural numbers (minimum `513` and maximum `287321` but there are some panel dropouts, i.e. `514`, `515`, `516`).

I need to preserve the panel feature of the data. Therefore, if a random id is chosen, any year-id combination has to be kept. I do not need a random sample of the data (neither 10% or nor 10 observations). Rather I am interested in a random id-number from my id-column/variable, stored in a way that I can subsequently use it.

Thus, I am looking for a command like "pick one random value out of the given set of values from column ID". I subsequently want to use this randomly picked id in commands such as:

```
xtline income if id==X
```

Which is supposed to show me the income for **all year** of random person/ID X.

Comment: Please read [How to create high quality reproducible examples in Stata](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377015/how-to-create-high-quality-reproducible-examples-in-stata) for tips on how to improve your question. Especially for providing example data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reproducible-examples-guide. I will check out soon. You're suggestion works fine for a random percentage. But my dataset is so huge, that even small percentages are too much. How can I adjust this to "10 cases" instead of "10 percent"? Regards

Comment: I will give you a hint: check the help file for the `sample` command.

Comment: I know there is a `count` feature, I try to check ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't well explained, at least at first, but I think you want to select panels randomly. The method below selects first observations randomly and then extends any selection to each entire panel. It doesn't take account of the number of observations in any panel. Flagging a selection with -1 is just a minor device so that selected observations sort early. The magic number 5 -- replace with any magic number of panels -- is the number of panels selected (not a percent), which is what you're asking for.

```
clear
input float(year id income)
2003 513  500
2004 513 1000
2003 517  500
2004 517  120
2003 518  100
2004 523  300
2003 525  900
2004 525  700
2003 528  800
2004 528  800
2003 531    0
2004 531  200
2003 532  300
2004 532  600
2003 534  600
2004 534  100
end

list, sepby(id) 

     +---------------------+
     | year    id   income |
     |---------------------|
  1. | 2003   513      500 |
  2. | 2004   513     1000 |
     |---------------------|
  3. | 2003   517      500 |
  4. | 2004   517      120 |
     |---------------------|
  5. | 2003   518      100 |
     |---------------------|
  6. | 2004   523      300 |
     |---------------------|
  7. | 2003   525      900 |
  8. | 2004   525      700 |
     |---------------------|
  9. | 2003   528      800 |
 10. | 2004   528      800 |
     |---------------------|
 11. | 2003   531        0 |
 12. | 2004   531      200 |
     |---------------------|
 13. | 2003   532      300 |
 14. | 2004   532      600 |
     |---------------------|
 15. | 2003   534      600 |
 16. | 2004   534      100 |
     +---------------------+

bysort id : gen byte first = -(_n == 1)
set seed 1776
gen rnd = runiform()
sort first rnd
gen wanted = _n <= 5
bysort id (wanted) : replace wanted = wanted[_N]
sort id year

list id year if wanted, sepby(id)

     +------------+
     |  id   year |
     |------------|
  7. | 525   2003 |
  8. | 525   2004 |
     |------------|
  9. | 528   2003 |
 10. | 528   2004 |
     |------------|
 11. | 531   2003 |
 12. | 531   2004 |
     |------------|
 13. | 532   2003 |
 14. | 532   2004 |
     |------------|
 15. | 534   2003 |
 16. | 534   2004 |
     +------------+
```

Comment: That's a perfect visual outcome Mr. Cox. But how can I store these 5 randoms IDs? In order to use them in commands like `xtlin`? Best regards

Comment: The variable `wanted` flags selected panels. There is no need to store the identifiers.  `xtline ... if wanted` selects the panels and observations you want. (You could `keep if wanted` which will make some things easier.) As you appear to be a Stata beginner, I would recommend Statalist. SO isn't really for asking questions about languages you hardly understand.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice Mr. Cox (I recognized some time ago, that you are an expert in the field). Here's my final problem: `xtline` doesn't produce anything. There is no error message, the server I work on can't be out of memory. I often produced `xtline` for 5 IDs before. Also `histogram income if wanted` works fine. What else could be problematic with my data, that makes `xtline` running and running? Regards

Comment: If you have a large dataset, `xtline` will spend most of its time not selecting data you don't want. That is why I flagged that `keep if wanted` could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get what you want is this:

```
clear

input year id var
2003 513 5
2003 517 5
2003 523 6
2003 525 9
2003 528 8
2003 531 0
2003 532 3
2003 534 6
2004 513 10
2004 517 12
2004 523 3
2004 525 7
2004 528 8
2004 531 2
2004 532 6
2004 534 1
end

bysort year (id): sample 3, count

list, sepby(year)

     +------------------+
     | year    id   var |
     |------------------|
  1. | 2003   523     6 |
  2. | 2003   534     6 |
  3. | 2003   531     0 |
     |------------------|
  4. | 2004   517    12 |
  5. | 2004   523     3 |
  6. | 2004   532     6 |
     +------------------+
```

To sample a `10%` you get rid of the `count` option:

```
bysort year (id): sample 10
```

---

**EDIT:**

To randomly select the same observations in *all*  panels:

```
set seed 12345
generate random = runiform()
bysort id: replace random = random[1]
keep if random < 0.1

sort year (id)
list, sepby(year)

     +-----------------------------+
     | year    id   var     random |
     |-----------------------------|
  1. | 2003   523     6   .0039323 |
  2. | 2003   532     3   .0286627 |
     |-----------------------------|
  3. | 2004   523     3   .0039323 |
  4. | 2004   532     6   .0286627 |
     +-----------------------------+
```

Comment: In your selection, you randomly selected `id=523` (for both years), but `id=534` for only one year (2003).

Comment: So do you want to select panels randomly? Because this is a different thing.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot relate the size of my sample to the uniform distribution. Even if I change `keep if random < 0.001` there are too many obs left. The suggestion of Mr. Cox to "pick 5" is more suitable.

Comment: @Marco Sorry but I think you do not know what you want. If you look at the comments and question, every time I provide a solution, you add another problem in the equation. First you wanted to sample randomly, then you asked for the same observations, next you wanted 10%. Now you said you want fewer and you have issues with the `xtline` command. In the context of the original question and its subsequent edit my answer fully addresses your problem.

Comment: @PearlySpencer I appreciate your effort and apologize for my question style. At the same time, I stick to the phrasing "sample an item from a variable". It's like "pick a value from a column". I do not want to have a sample of my dataset, I would like to have a integer-number (that's why this item is) drawn from my variable/column. Kind Regards

Comment: The term "item" isn't well defined in data science that I know, but I think it connotes an individual observation in Stata if it connotes anything at all. I can't think it's a good word for panel, which is the term of art here.